# WPF DataGrid ColumnCount

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` with a `DataTable` as `DataGrid.ItemsSource`.

So far everything works fine and the Data is shown in the `DataGrid` as i want it to be.
Now I want to hide some of the Columns of the `DataGrid`. And I have done this before and it worked fine but somehow I always get an Error saying

"System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

I know what this means but I don't understand why this is happening.

Here's my code:

```
adapter.Fill(datatable);
NameDG.ItemsSource = datatable.DefaultView;

//Hide Column[1]
NameDG.Columns[1].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

The `DataGrid` has more then 10 Columns.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Is your adapter actually returning any data?  Have you tried debugging it, and checking (for example) the column count of the returned data?

Comment: When you debug, what is the content of NameDG.Columns? And what is NameDG.Columns.Length?

Comment: You can remove the column of datable if its not required, which inturn would not show up in DataGrid

Comment: Try only hiding one of the first columns, does that work? do keep in mind that the index is zero-based - hence, if you try to hide the last column without this in mind, you'll always get that error.

Comment: Okay, the adapter is returning data, and the data is shown in the DataGrid but somehow the Column.Count is 0 until I have the data loaded a second time, then it is the real Column.Count.
I solved the problem with having the Columns removed from the DataTable directly like Nobody suggested.
Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this thread I will answer the question myself after I found the solutions.

1. You can delet the Columns directly from the `DataTable` like for example through this (Thanks to Nobody)

   ```
   datatable.Columns.Remove(datatable.Columns[0]);
   ```

or

2. Use the `AutoGeneratedColumns` event handler from the `DataGrid`

Answer (score 0):

if you click the column name it's have a negative value specific value is -1 you need to validate it by using IF STATEMENT

use this event to prevent the error

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
int rowIndex = e.RowIndex;
if(rowIndex <= -1)
 {
 //Error
 }
 else
 {
//Your Code
 }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I solved with removing the Columns of the DataTalbe directly. But I don't think that your Code would solve my problem because I want the Columns removed right at the beginning and not after a ClickEvent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
   NameDG.Loaded += NameDG_Loaded;

    void NameDG_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NameDG.Columns[1].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
```